# Twitter stream works well, but suddenly it doesn’t work

Tags: python, twitter, stream

I used v2 to do Twitter filtered stream.

It worked well and started with a different value, but it didn’t appear for about a minute before Connection broken: ConnectionResetError appeared.
Connection broken: ConnectionResetError has not been working since it appeared.

The error is
Exception: Cannot add rules (HTTP 400): {“errors”:[{“parameters”:{“add”:},“message”:“Cannot deserialize value of type com.twitter.dataproducts.staf.stafrulesapi.controller.AddRule from String value (token JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)”}],“title”:“Invalid Request”,“detail”:“One or more parameters to your request was invalid.”,“type”:“invalid-request url”}

How do we get back to normal?

my code

```
import requests
import os
import json

# To set your enviornment variables in your terminal run the following line:
# export 'BEARER_TOKEN'='<your_bearer_token>'
bearer_token = "my token"


def bearer_oauth(r):
    """
    Method required by bearer token authentication.
    """

    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    r.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2FilteredStreamPython"
    return r


def get_rules():
    response = requests.get(
        "api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules", auth=bearer_oauth
    )
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot get rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
        )
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))
    return response.json()


def delete_all_rules(rules):
    if rules is None or "data" not in rules:
        return None

    ids = list(map(lambda rule: rule["id"], rules["data"]))
    payload = {"delete": {"ids": ids}}
    response = requests.post(
        "api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules",
        auth=bearer_oauth,
        json=payload
    )
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot delete rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))


def set_rules(delete):
    # You can adjust the rules if needed
    sample_rules = [
      {"value": "dog"},
    ]
    payload = {"add": sample_rules}
    response = requests.post(
        "api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules",
        auth=bearer_oauth,
        json=payload,
    )
    if response.status_code != 201:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot add rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
        )
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))


def get_stream(set):
    response = requests.get(
        "api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream", auth=bearer_oauth, stream=True,
    )
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot get stream (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    for response_line in response.iter_lines():
        if response_line:
            json_response = json.loads(response_line)
            print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
           


def main():
    rules = get_rules()
    delete = delete_all_rules(rules)
    set = set_rules(delete)
    get_stream(set)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: “type”:“invalid-request url” is "type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"

Comment: maybe they change something in Twitter and now code needs changes - and you may need to wait for newer version. Maybe first find repo with source code and check if there are reported `issues`